# Clear cell in row if another cell in the same row is blank

Tags: vba, excel

This code will delete the entire row if it finds an empty cell in column G. What I need to do is clear the cell in column A if the cell in column G is blank.

```
On Error Resume Next     ' In case there are no blanks
Columns("G:G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.UsedRange 'Resets UsedRange for Excel 97
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
With Intersect(Columns("G:G"), ActiveSheet.UsedRange)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(.Cells) > 0 Then
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(, -6).ClearContents
    End If
End With
```

Comment: +1 nice use of the CountBlank rather than the standard error checking

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
Columns("G:G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(0,-6).ClearContents
```

Answer (score 0):

Like so:

```
On Error Resume Next     ' In case there are no blanks
Columns("G:G").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Offset(, -6) = ""
```

Comment: If you are going to resort to error handling (On Error Resume Next), do not forget to reset it afterwards (On Error Goto 0)